# How to check whether ANTLR4 rule is null?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying this (it's just an example):

```
foo:
  bar?
  { if ($bar == null) { ... } }
  ;
```

ANTLR4 compiler says:

```
Message{errorType=ISOLATED_RULE_REF, args=[bar, $bar] ...
```

What is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally the action you have written above would be placed in the `exitFoo` method of a listener which you use after the parse is complete.

However, if you do leave the action in the grammar, to reference the context object itself, use the `ctx` property. For example, `$bar.ctx` is the expression you are trying to use here, and `$ctx` evaluates to the context object for the enclosing rule.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the FAQ [How do I test if an optional rule was matched?](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5373957) ;)